# How to amortise revenue / cost by month in SQL (ideally PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, amortized-analysis

I summarise revenue and cost comparison usually in excel. I would like to know if I can achieve the following transformation within SQL, ideally PostgreSQL:

From this table:

[From this table | you see the long data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h6NZ.png)

To this table:
[To this table | you see the wide data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01kcC.png)

Please ignore the bad formatting.

Thanks a lot for any help!

In SQL I have not had any progress yet.

In Excel, I set up the month-year column first and if the revenue/cost period falls in the range, the numbers will show under that month/year. Then i will transform to Pivot table.

Comment: "Please ignore the bad formatting." -> Which formatting? We don't see sample input data and we also don't see the expected outcome. Please add both as tables in your question. There are some links in your question that obviously lead off from Stackoverflow to external sites. Since people should not risk to land on spam sites, please remove them.

Comment: Surely this can be done, but why not do it in Excel? It seems more like a formatting challange than a data challange to me.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Hi, the sample screenshots are in the links-- if you open these 2 links you can see the tables i was referring to. Let me try editing it... somehow the pictures wont show here.